# Did AirFone ever make money?

Tags: radio-communications

I remember when the first AirFones were put into service in 1990s and marveled at who would be rich enough to pay $7/min for air to ground phone service.

Even though every seat eventually had an AirFone, I cannot once recall seeing one in use (except in movies) in twenty years of flying (in economy).

I know they're being pulled out now, but did AirFones ever make a profit? Who paid for their installation, was it the airlines or did GTE etc pay for everything?

Comment: I imagine onboard Wi-Fi will be used much more.  Especially by businessmen and women.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not according to the authors of [The 4 A's of Marketing](http://rajsisodia.com/raj/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/4As-of-Marketing-Introduction-and-Chapter-1.pdf) <sup>[1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sxKpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16)</sup>

> Despite impressive technological achievements and great expectations all around, the service’s business performance ultimately proved an **abject failure**. In the ten years before Verizon finally pulled the plug, Airfone generated only 50 million total calls, a fraction of the calls carried daily by cellular companies. While the Airfone service was heavily used when bad weather caused significant delays, the system’s utilization at other times was extremely low. A typical plane was equipped with as many as 60 phones. From these, the average large jet generated fewer than 100 calls per day in about 16 hours of flying time. As a result, **the expensive system, with its heavy load of fixed costs, remained idle well over 99% of the time.**
>
> ...
>
> While Airfone claimed that some customers’ monthly bills topped out
>   at $4,000, there were not nearly enough of them to sustain the service’s sky-high fixed
>   costs.
>
> ...
>
> Within a few years of the service’s launch, airlines started to remove the expensive phone
>   infrastructure from their cabins, since **the Airfone cost them more in increased fuel
>   consumption (because of the system’s weight) than it generated revenues** through their
>   revenue sharing arrangement with Verizon.

My emphasis.

Comment: Perfect answer. Interesting that at 100 calls per 16 hours, that's still 6 calls an hour per plane. Maybe it was all front of the cabin folks.

Comment: I can't imagine many people are sitting in economy but paying $70 for a ten minute call?

Comment: One wonders why they bothered to put the phones in the back of the plane anyway.

Comment: *I* wonder why they never simply dropped the rates to be affordable. Even if they weren't able to get to a point to make money, they would have been losing less.